# SendGrid "helping" me by changing my html template when I save?

Tags: html, css, templates, sendgrid

I create a default template in SendGrid, for use in their transactional api. I then add an img link with a float: right in it. When I hit "save" in their editor, it wipes the float from my image and inserts a new class called sg-image in it. This messes up my styles, of course. Anyone ever seen this or know why Sendgrid is  with my template? I cannot find any documentation about it, and their support team is unresponsive to my bug report.

Before:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>&lt;%body%&gt;</div>
 <a href="%STORYURL1%" style="color:#333332;text-decoration:none">
   <img src="%STORYPIC1%" height="122" style="float:right !important; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; margin-left:7px;"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

After

```html
    <html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>&lt;%body%&gt;</div>

<div><a href="%STORYURL1%" style="color:#333332;text-decoration:none"><span class="sg-image" data-imagelibrary="%7B%22width%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22122%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22%22%2C%22border%22%3A1%2C%22src%22%3A%22%25STORYPIC1%25%22%2C%22classes%22%3A%7B%22sg-image%22%3A1%7D%7D"><img height="122" src="%STORYPIC1%" style="border: 1px solid transparent; margin-left: 7px; height: 122px;" /></span></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

We have been experiencing this exact issue for months and have ended up not using their terrible template system and building our own. Anyway they finally admitted the problem and came back with a solution/ work around.

The solution they have provided:

Hello,
Here is a solution an engineer has provided:
Example:

```
<td><span class="sg-image" data-imagelibrary="%7B%22width%22%3A%22160%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22200%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%20%7D%7D%20-%20%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27name%27%5D%20%7D%7D%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22border%22%3A0%2C%22src%22%3A%22http%3A//cdn.fakewebsite.st/image/%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%7Creplace%28%7B%27%3A%27%3A%20%27-%27%7D%29%20%7D%7D.png%22%2C%22classes%22%3A%7B%22sg-image%22%3A1%7D%7D" style="float: none; display: block; text-align: center;"><a href="https://fakewebsite.st/?utm_source=blah&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=v1" target="_blank"><img alt=" - " height="200" src="http://cdn.fakewebsite.st/image/{{ uc[2]['uniqueSymbol']|replace({':': '-'}) }}.png" style="width: 160px; height: 200px;" width="160" /></a></span></td>
```

Take a look at "data-imagelibrary". This is URL encoded information about the image that is supposed to be used.
data-imagelibrary:

```
%7B%22width%22%3A%22160%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22200%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%20%7D%7D%20-%20%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27name%27%5D%20%7D%7D%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22border%22%3A0%2C%22src%22%3A%22http%3A//cdn.fakewebsite.st/image/%7B%7B%20uc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%7Creplace%28%7B%27%3A%27%3A%20%27-%27%7D%29%20%7D%7D.png%22%2C%22classes%22%3A%7B%22sg-image%22%3A1%7D%7D
```

data-imagelibrary decoded:

```
{"width":"160","height":"200","alt_text":" - ","alignment":"center","border":0,"src":"http://cdn.fakewebsite.st/image/{{ uc[2]['uniqueSymbol']|replace({':': '-'}) }}.png","classes":{"sg-image":1}}
You can make changes to this data and then re-encode:
{"width":"160","height":"200","alt_text":" - ","alignment":"center","border":0,"src":"http://cdn.fakewebsite.st/image/{{ hc[2]['uniqueSymbol']|replace({':': '-'}) }}.png","classes":{"sg-image":1}}
```

Re-encoded:

```
%7B%22width%22%3A%22160%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22200%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22%7B%7B%20hc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%20%7D%7D%20-%20%7B%7B%20hc%5B2%5D%5B%27name%27%5D%20%7D%7D%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22border%22%3A0%2C%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.fakewebsite.st%2Fimage%2F%7B%7B%20hc%5B2%5D%5B%27uniqueSymbol%27%5D%7Creplace(%7B%27%3A%27%3A%20%27-%27%7D)%20%7D%7D.png%22%2C%22classes%22%3A%7B%22sg-image%22%3A1%7D%7D
```

You can put the URL encoded information back into the HTML and it should change the code.
Let me know if this is helpful.

### Regards,

SendGrid Support

Comment: I ended up rewriting my template to move the styling outside the IMG tag, so have worked around it that way. But so I am clear, the suggestion is to remove the IMG tag and replace it with this html snippet above?

Comment: No what they are saying is that the data-imagelibrary tag contents encoded content that then ends up replacing the tags you are entering, hence when you save it overwrites what you change. So you need to change this encoded content, or maybe remove it....

Comment: In my case, adding the width and height attribute to the <img> tags solved my problem. `<img width="100%" height="auto" ... />`

Comment: I wrapped all my <img /> tags in my own <span></span> which has helped SendGrid's code figure out where to inject their [stupid, annoying, broken] custom image spans.  At least it doesn't completely screw up my email markup anymore.

Comment: Nevermind, I take it back.  This will just result in an endless supply of additional nested spans for each time you save.